How to show OTP from sms android
I have other project(in xml), in that project I don't use anything like permission(READ_SMS) or launcher from API(google) to get OTP from message. I want to do the same with my new project(compose), but its not working and there is no information about this.. do anyone know how??
this is the result that I want

